# Journalling in AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

I used dspjrn command to take the journals for a file in as400. In resultant journal, all decimal fields has become zeros, even if there is a value for those fields in the file. What could be the reason?

Comment: _(Very uninformed guess)_ Maybe the file was not encoded in EBCDIC.

Comment: Please show an example of what you are seeing in the journal compared to the data actually in the file. Include all of the entry data

Comment: The data in the actual file : 
20.180.531           1      12              0                       0                   0            0             240.000   20.121.001
Data in the Journals:
Update Before: 20180531   112  0              00000000      20121001       00000000
Update After: 20180531   112  0              00000000      20121001       00000000

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two possibilities

1) You're looking at an "after image" for a delete transaction
2) The journal is configured to minimize entry data.

For #1, look at the "before" image if available, or look for the "after" image of the prior insert/update.

For #2, Look at the Minimize entry data setting show via  Work with Journal Attributes (WRKJRNA)

The available options as shown here [Create Journal (CRTJRN) - MINENTDTA parameter](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_72/cl/crtjrn.htm#CRTJRN.MINENTDTA)

> Minimize entry specific data (MINENTDTA) Specifies which object types
>   allow journal entries to have minimized entry specific data.
>
> Journal receivers using the *FLDBDY option to minimize the entry
>   specific data cannot be saved and restored to any release prior to
>   V5R4M0 nor can they be replicated to any remote journal on a system at
>   a release prior to V5R4M0. See the Journal management topic collection
>   in the IBM i Information Center at
>   http://www.ibm.com/systems/i/infocenter/ for restrictions and usage of
>   journal entries with minimized entry specific data.
>
> *NONE No object type allows a journal entry with minimized entry specific data. Journal entries for all journaled objects will be
>   deposited in the journal with complete entry specific data.
>   *FILE Journaled files may have journal entries deposited with minimized entry specific data. The minimizing will not occur on field
>   boundaries. Therefore, the entry specific data may not be viewable and
>   may not be used for auditing purposes. This value cannot be specified
>   if *FLDBDY is specified.
>   *FLDBDY Journaled files may have journal entries deposited with minimized entry specific data. The minimizing for journaled files will
>   occur on field boundaries. Therefore, the entry specific data will be
>   viewable and may be used for auditing purposes
>   *DTAARA Journaled data areas may have journal entries deposited with minimized entry specific data.